# Hide unselected features with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

In the context of QGIS/PyQGIS, I would like to hide the unselected features after performing, for example, a simple selection.

```
feature = layer.getFeatures().next()
layer.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
```

After running this commands a feature becomes highlighted. Besides, I'd like to hide the unselected features. How can I do that?

I believe this is possible because the Query Builder performs a filter that hides the undesired features.

Comment: The **QgsVectorLayer** method is 'deselect' and the parameter is the 'id' of selected feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made it. In fact, I should use the setSubsetString method. Then I built a a query string inside a loop in order to look like this "gid IN ('8816','8836','8839','8864')". Then, when you run the setSubsetString method it hides the features that are not specified in the query string.

```
#Do any spacial query which returns some features
features = lyrPnts.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(geomPoly.boundingBox()))

#build the query string
strsel="gid IN ("
for feat in features:
    if feat.geometry().intersects(geomPoly):
        strsel=strsel+ "'" + str(feat.id()) + "',"

#Closes the string with a parenthesis
strsel=strsel[:-1] + ")"
#Hides the undesired features
lyrPnts.setSubsetString(strsel)
```

Nice job

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Features are controlled by the renderer, you cannot just "hide" a feature (unless you delete it). Instead you will have to setup a rule that matches a given property (in your case selection) to define the rendering parameters.

Have a look at the expressions+ plugin. There is a function called `isselected(layername)` which can be used in a style to control the transparency in any renderer or to only match the selected features in a rulebased renderer.