# Hiding specific points in shapefile layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point

I am using QGIS 2.18.2 on a Macbook Pro running OS X 10.10.5.

I created a layer of only 8 points from a wildlife survey. A few points have become less relevant, so I want to hide them from the display. But I would rather not delete them from the shapefile.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to create a new, separate layer of the relevant points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this by:

- adding a column to the attribute table, name that "visible"
- check those points that you don't want to be visible as "no".
- in the shapefile properties (doubleclick on the shapefile) select properties>style>categorized>
- select the "visible" column, and click on 'classify'
- EITHER delete the "no" records from the style dialog window
- OR uncheck their visibility checkbox
- OR make them completely transparent

Answer (score 5):

If it is ok to add a field to determine show / no show of your points, for instance:

[image]

"Rule-based" styling can be set as "Show" = 'show' and "Show" = 'no show'.

On *Rule properties* window (by double-clicking on the 'no show' rule), you can tick-off the small box next to **Symbol**. This turns off symbol appearance.

[image]

When you need the hidden points back, turn the box on.

Answer (score 5):

As long as there are only a few points to be hidden you could easily filter them even by listing their IDs (if necessary, when the respective points don't share a common attribute):

- right-click the layer in layer-window
- select 'Filter...'
- type " 'ID' NOT IN ('id1','id2',...) " with 'id' being the point-IDs to hide and 'ID' the (name of the) unique ID-field

You can apply the same rule to any field-name / value combination to identify your points to hide, in case of an (unlikely) missing ID field.

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to set the **Provider feature filter** which can be accessed by right-clicking your layer and going to `Properties > General > Provider feature filter`. This allows you to filter your features based on their attributes. We can use this to hide certain features. What I used to do was (based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167282/hide-unselected-features-with-pyqgis)):

---

1. Create a new field in your layer and use the expression:

   ```
   $id
   ```

   This returns the feature id. Then save the edits.

---

2. Run the following code into the **Python Console**, this will programmatically set the filter. So you basically select the points you want hidden and the code will create the filter based on those selected points:

   ```
   def hide(field):
       layer = iface.activeLayer()
       expr = str(field) + " NOT IN ("
       for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
           expr = expr + "'" + str(feat.id()) + "',"   
       expr = expr[:-1] + ")"  
       layer.setSubsetString(expr)
   ```

---

3. Select the points you want hidden and (assuming the field name which contains the feature id is called `"ID"`) then type the following in the python console:

   ```
   hide('ID')
   ```

   Notice the single quotes. Your selected points should now be hidden.